# Relative links with Razor in ASP.NET without MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor, razor-2

We're working on a site that was set up with all the pages in the root directory. As a result all the links are referencing locations in the same directory they're located in by default...

```
<a href="Page.cshtml">Page</a>
```

We've restructured it and some of the pages are now in sub folders, so the links throughout the site now need to be relative. I've read that a tilde (~) won't work in the markup when using Razor. ie `<a href="~/Page.cshtml">Page</a>`

How can a link be formatted so that it points to something in the root directory?

Something like? `<a href="@Href("~/Page.cshtml")">Page</a>`

**EDIT:** Resolved with: `<a href="@Href("~/")Page.cshtml">Page</a>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@helper _href(string url)
{
    @VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(url)
}
```

To use it on a page:

`<a href="@_href("~/page.html")">linky</a>`

Edit: How I never knew about the built-in Href method is beyond me. You should definitely use that instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, actually just found an easier work around, I'll make an edit to the original post.

Comment: Your workaround doesn't make much sense. Why use `@Href("~/")Page.cshtml` instead of `@Href("~/Page.cshtml")`. The latter is cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: It could be added through out the site in seconds with find and replace, we'll probably change it to clean it up down the road.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Href](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.webpages.webpageexecutingbase.href) method, like this:

```
@Href("SomePage")
```

Note that you don't need to use file extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Glance at @Html.ActionLink

It allows you use controller name

Comment: We're not using MVC though.

Comment: Even if he was using MVC, you would never use ActionLink to refer to static content. That's what `@Url.Content()` is for.